# How can I return more than two variables while in 'Class'?

Tags: python

```
def main() :
    a = Dog('Welsh corgi','Max')
    b = Dog('Poodle','Charlie')
    a.add_trick('Wallowing')
    b.add_trick('Running')
    b.add_trick('Jumping')
    print(a)
    print(b)

class Dog:
    def __init__(self, kind, name):
        self.__kind = kind
        self.__name = name

    def kind(self):
        self.__kind = kind

    def name(self):
        self.__name = name
    
    def add_trick(self, tricks):
        self.__tricks = tricks
        return self.__tricks

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s can do %s" %(self.__kind, self.__name, self.__tricks)

main()
```

I want to print both 'Running', 'Jumping' but only Jumping (later one). I think I should fix 'return self.__tricks' but don't know how. How can I return all of the 'tricks' in the final "%s %s can do %s".

Comment: Make `self.__tricks` a *list* (initialised in `__init__`) and append tricks to that list…?! It has nothing much to do with returning anything from `add_trick`.

Comment: One underscore is enough to mark field private, btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make tricks as list and append new tricks in list like this:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, kind, name):
        self.__kind = kind
        self.__name = name
        self.__tricks = []

    def add_trick(self, tricks):
        self.__tricks.append(tricks)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s can do %s" % (self.__kind, self.__name, ' '.join(self.__tricks))
```